# Share ssh keys between two different pcs that I own

Tags: ssh

I have a ssh key on a PC called name_machine, I can send my public key to a server admin, but only once. If I want to use the same key on 2 or more pcs, should I only copy the private one between my pcs or I should also change their name to match name_machine present in the public key that I sent?

Comment: You don't have to change a pc's name.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work and I cannot understand why.
Why in the public key there is my user@my_machine_name ?? Can someone explain it?

Comment: user@my_machine_name is a comment and not a part of a key

Comment: what OS do you use?

Comment: I am on Debian. 
If user@my_machine is a comment, it doesn't matter if it doesn't match exactly the current user and machine name??
I have only to copy the file to the .ssh folder of another pc??

Comment: yes, you have to copy your private key to .ssh folder.

Comment: i am going to try with github to test if it works